# Lightbox 1 Close Button Pointer off

Tags: javascript

In browsers Safari and Chrome the "Close" link at the bottom The cursor pointer is off. A visitor has to mouse below the word "Close" to see the pointer. Is there a fix for this?

Click on image on this page to See Example" http://millay.org/volunteer.php

Thanks,
Billy

Answer (score 0):

Add this class

```
#bottomNavClose {position:relative;}
```